# xmlhttprequest cannot load no 'access-control-allow-origin' only with post method (Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors

hi i am using angularjs and .net web api for my project. when i get data by GET method it work properly. But when i save data (POST) it give me error.

1.Code to get data in  (It Work Fine)

```
A) angular service

return $http.get(API_URL + '/Accounting/GetFeeGroup');

B) Web API

[HttpGet]
    public List<FeeGroup> GetFeeGroup()
    {
        return _feeGroupRepository.GetFeeGroup();
    }
```

2.Code To Save Data (It Give Error)

```
A) angular service
var data = { 'FeeGroupID': "" + scope.FeeGroupID + "", 'FeeGroupName': "" + scope.FeeGroupName + "" }
    $http({
        url: API_URL + '/Accounting/SaveFeeGroup',
        method: "post",
        data: data,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
    .success(function (data) {
        showSuccessMessage("Data Save Successfully");
        scope.GetFeeGroup();
    })

 B) Web API
[HttpPost]
    public long SaveFeeGroup(FeeGroup feeGroup)
    {
        return _feeGroupRepository.Save(feeGroup);
    }
```

This give error like this

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8081/api/Accounting/SaveFeeGroup. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8082' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

i already do CORS origin thing

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Please Help me it's so complicated for me that why it give error only with POST method.

Comment: when you look at the response headers in the browser, can you see the CORS headers being sent? See the word `preflight` in the error? Does your server side handle the OPTIONS request correctly?

Comment: here is the error :- XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8081/api/Accounting/SaveFeeGroup. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8082' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: yes it have the word "preflight"

Comment: yes, I know that's the error - see how it mentions `preflight` - that's why I asked if your **server** code handles `OPTIONS` type of request - it's like GET, POST, PUT, DELETE etc, only it's OPTIONS - please show ALL response headers you get to that request

Comment: `yes it have the word "preflight"` - yes, it does, because it does in your question (did you not read your question at all?)

Comment: I am new to this things but in my web.config i do this thing 
 <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <!--<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />-->
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
is it correct

Comment: do u have any solution for this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the CORS exception messages are misleading. The key exception here is the HTTP status code 404 at the end of the message below:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8081/api/Accounting/SaveFeeGroup. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8082' is therefore not allowed
>   access. ***The response had HTTP status code 404***.

Therefore, you can make sure the **Web API route** matches the one from the Angular App. I assume you're setting your routes elsewhere but if you are using Web API 2, you can do as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Accounting/SaveFeeGroup")]
public long SaveFeeGroup([FromBody]FeeGroup feeGroup)
{
    return _feeGroupRepository.Save(feeGroup);
}
```

Note the **[FromBody]** attribute which will enable you to bind your model to the Web API controller.

You can also try to change,

> var data = { 'FeeGroupID': "" + scope.FeeGroupID + "", 'FeeGroupName':
>   "" + scope.FeeGroupName + "" }

to:

> var data = {'FeeGroupID': scope.FeeGroupID, 'FeeGroupName':
>   scope.FeeGroupName};

**Edit: Troubleshooting**
Since CORS exception is thrown by Chrome, do the following to get rid of it and expose the real exception from the Web API.
Exit chrome(kill all instances). Press Windows Icon then letter R as you keep windows key down. Paste the command below on the resulting box and press enter.

> chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session"
>   --disable-web-security

This will open Chrome with **websecurity** disabled(no CORS filter). Make sure there's a warning message on chrome when it opens. Run your app and let me know what you get as an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can try set the default "Content-Type" as below:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

**Update**

Js Code should be like this.

```
var feeGroup = {'FeeGroupID' :scope.FeeGroupID,'FeeGroupName':scope.FeeGroupName};

$http({
    url: API_URL + '/Accounting/SaveFeeGroup',
    method: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify(feeGroup),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
```

Make sure your class property as follow.

```
public class FeeGroup 
{
    public long FeeGroupID { get; set; }
    public string FeeGroupName { get; set; }
}
```

Follow this link for more information [angularjs ajax call](http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/).

Comment: it solve the error but on the api side i am unable to get data

Comment: any solution for that

Comment: this is my class file

Comment: public partial class FeeGroup
    {
        public long FeeGroupID { get; set; }
        public string FeeGroupName { get; set; }
    }

Comment: still will work for you try with my code, But If you are not going to store a long value that you should do with int data type

Comment: i am using entity framework so class is created automatically

Comment: did u try current code? And in my answer also i have updated int to long so don't worry

Comment: any other solution

Comment: Please check are u getting something in scope.FeeGroupID and scope.FeeGroupName at client side